FTP Client Login Fails for cPanel FTP Account
When creating an FTP account in cPanel, the Directory field in the creation page always defaults to:
/home/my_cPanel_UserID/my_domain.com/my_ftp_UserID

The directory is created, but login attempts fail with access denied.

In this use case, clear the /my_domain.com/my_ftp_UserID in the FTP account creation dialog, so the Directory field is:
/home/my_cPanel_UserID

Login attempts now succeed.

If ever In this scenario the decision is taken to delete the FTP account, take care not to check the box "Delete User Directory", as it will nix all files on the site for my_cPanel_UserID.
